# Structuring and Querying Firebase Data Guidance Needed

Tags: json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

so lets say I have Houses, and each House has a set of users, a House name, and messages within the House.

Thank you.

My attempt at this:

```
{
"users": {
  // 433 is a random id
  "433": {
    "name": "Janet",
     // Index Janet's houses
    "houses": {
     "239WashingtonDr": true,
     "451CornellSt": true
  }

},
...
},
"houses": {
   // 239WashingtonDr is a random id 
   "239WashingtonDr": {
     "name": "Janet's house",
     "members": {
     "Janet": true,
     "Peter": true,
     "Kent": true
  }
},

}
}
```

Also, is anyone uses Swift, or Java. How would I be able to query which houses Janet's in?

Comment: This seems to be a two part question. @FrankvanPuffelen answered the query part, what was the first part of the question? It was kind of vague. Also, that Firebase structure may get you into trouble; since you are storing users by the uid, you should reference that uid in the houses/members section. i.e. 433: true. The reason for that is if you have three Janet's in your database, how would you know which Janet is which?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
let janetRef = ref.child("users").child("433");
janetRef.child("houses").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.key)
})
```

If you don't know the ID of Janet's node, you can look all users with name Janet up with:

```
let janets = ref.queryOrderedByChild("name").queryEqualToValue("janet")
janets.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print(snapshot.key)
})
```